# Entity Framework relationships with composite keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have two tables:

`User` table with primary key `UserId`.

`Follow` table with primary key `FollowId`.

The `Follow` table has a column called `FollowedId` which can mean the primary key of several entities, including `User`, `Keyword`, `City`, `Business` etc.

There is an additional column in the `Follow` table called `FollowedTypeId`, this indicates which entity the `FollowedId` represents.

How can I create a navigation property on the `User` table and have that automatically populated with all it's related entities in the `Follow` table?

I've been looking up composite keys and how to map but I'm afraid I've not yet been able to understand how to accomplish this.

Comment: You can't. Polymorphic associations are not suuported by EF, only relationships which can be represented by FK constraint in the relational database.

Comment: check Table per Type (TPT) relationship. https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks everyone :)